# How to instanciate vscode.ExtensionContext manually?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Usually, `vscode.ExtensionContext` is provided when calling `activate` method.
But how can I instanciate it manually?

Comment: where do you want to create an `ExtensionContext`

Comment: I want to create it in the test file.

Comment: You'd better give up that idea of mocking the classes on your own. Follow the standard testing suggestions, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the intro example is misleading and other people are confused too, see:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/issues/378
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155206

You need to do something like:

```js
test('extension activates without crashing', () => {
    const extension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('klondikemarlen.create-test-file');

    assert.ok(extension !== undefined, "Extension is undefined");
    const typedExtension = extension as vscode.Extension<any>;

    assert.doesNotThrow(() => {
        typedExtension.activate();
    });
});
```

If you wanted to get the context at that point, your `activate()` function would need to return it.
e.g.

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // register some commands or something

    return context
}
```

and then you could do

```js
const context = typedExtension.activate()
// do something with context
```